# fixed sidebar overlapping page content?

Tags: html, css, center, sidebar, overlap

I made a sidebar using CSS and HTML. However, when I try to put in some content on my HTML page no matter what I do, it goes on the top left of the page, under the sidebar.  How can I place fixed content on the right-hand side of the page?

Below shows my CSS codes, please let me know if there is a thing that prevents the main content from going in the right-center of the page.

```css
.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 175px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link href="myMenuStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Bungee+Hairline&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="import" href="TableOfContent.html">
  <title>about me</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="cool.ico">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- The sidebar -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a id='one' href="TableOfContent.html" style="font-weight: bold">Table of Content</a>
    <p><u>Visual Communication:</u></p>
    <bl>
      <a id='two' class='click' href="GraphicD.html">Graphic Design</a>
      <a id='three' class='click' href="Illustration.html">Illustration</a>
      <a id='four' class='click' href="Photography.html">Photography</a>
      <p><u>Multi Media/Digital Media:</u></p>
      <a id='five' class='click' href="Scripting.html">Scripting</a>
      <a id='six' class='click' href="Sound.html">Sound</a>
      <p><u>Programming:</u></p>
      <a id='seven' class='click' href="Coding.html">Coding</a>
      <a id='eight' class='click' href="Game.html">Interactive/Game Design</a>
      <a id='nine' class='click' href="Arduino.html">Hardware/Electrical Circuit</a>
      <p><br></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Page content -->
  <p>Testing</p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to show your HTML code for us to debug the problem.

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta thank you for letting me know, I edited it.

Comment: You could do this by putting all the main content within one tag, like the `<main>` and then just add a `border-left: 175px;` to the main page content (the `<main>` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first define a flexbox layout to organize the content from left to right, in contrast to the default HTML DOM behavior of top to bottom. You do this by first wrapping the entire container in a `div` and applying `display: flex` on it. You then set the `flex-direction: row` to order it left to right. Nevertheless when you define a block as `position: fixed` it is brought out of the document model and thus your right side content is displayed under the left `fixed` position block. To overcome this apply a left margin to your right side content (lets say about 15%, based on your left container width).

I made a couple of changes to the HTML file to apply the flexbox:

```css
.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 175px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link href="myMenuStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Bungee+Hairline&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="import" href="TableOfContent.html">
  <title>about me</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="cool.ico">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- The sidebar -->
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <a id='one' href="TableOfContent.html" style="font-weight: bold">Table of 
    Content</a>
      <p><u>Visual Communication:</u></p>
      <bl>
        <a id='two' class='click' href="GraphicD.html">Graphic Design</a>
        <a id='three' class='click' href="Illustration.html">Illustration</a>
        <a id='four' class='click' href="Photography.html">Photography</a>
        <p><u>Multi Media/Digital Media:</u></p>
        <a id='five' class='click' href="Scripting.html">Scripting</a>
        <a id='six' class='click' href="Sound.html">Sound</a>
        <p><u>Programming:</u></p>
        <a id='seven' class='click' href="Coding.html">Coding</a>
        <a id='eight' class='click' href="Game.html">Interactive/Game Design</a>
        <a id='nine' class='click' href="Arduino.html">Hardware/Electrical Circuit</a>
        <p><br></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="content">
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For more information about Flexbox - [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)