# css position:fixed overlapping

Tags: html, css

My problem is really simple,

I just want to add a menu (navbar) to the side of my page, therfore I gave it `position fixed`. The problem with that is, that all html elements I try to add ignore it.
[Problem posistion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaZIN.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fixed sidebar overlapping page content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66395518/fixed-sidebar-overlapping-page-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you position an element with:

- `position: absolute`; or
- `position: fixed`

this removes the element from the **document flow** which means, as you've noticed, that all other elements will ignore that *out-of-flow* positioned element and appear over the top of it etc.

You can use `padding` and `margin` on other elements to ensure that they don't overlap the *out-of-flow* positioned element.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 127);
}

main {
  margin-left: 156px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Main Page</h1>
  <p> This is the main part of the page.</p>
  <p>It has a <code>margin-left</code> of <code>156px</code>.</p>
</main>

<nav>
  <h2>Navigation</h2>
  
  <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
    <li>Page 5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is there no way to integrate it in the document flow

Comment: There are other approaches - using CSS Floats, for example - which enable other elements to "be aware" of the element you are positioning. But if you apply a `fixed` or `absolute` position to an element, you are explicitly instructing that that element should be lifted out of the document flow.

Comment: the CSS Floats working great

thanks for the help!